# What is a English noun without determiner?

Tags: prepositions, nouns, syntax, determiners

I read a sentence today:

> The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) uses a retransmission timer to ensure data delivery ***in the absence of*** any feedback from the remote data receiver.

I saw ***in the ... of*** for many times, and I'm really curious about the ***in*** in it and I found the Oxford Dictionary told me that:

> ***IN***: (often followed by a noun without a determiner) expressing a state or condition.

It seems that the ***absence*** in this sentence is "a noun without determiner". I'm confused about that. What is a English noun without determiner?

Comment: Examples of **in** followed by a noun without **a** determiner are: in shock, in grief, in labour, in fear... all 'a state or condition'.

Comment: It's generally non-count nouns that can function without a determiner. With just a few exceptions count nouns require one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of “in the absence of” is the same as in

> She found the pickles **in the back of** the refrigerator.

(Note that in British English, it would usually be “**at** the back.”)

Your *absence* does have a determiner: *the*.

*Oxford* is talking about things like

> When the menacing group of men surrounded him, he knew he was **in trouble**.

Comment: Thanks. Furthermore, is "in the absence of ..." an adj of "data delivery" or an adv of "ensure"?

Comment: It’s modifying *delivery*. Consider this: “In the absence of feedback, delivery cannot be assumed; further measures must be employed to ensure it.”